# How to convert XML strings to JSON in Erlang?

Tags: json, xml, erlang

I want to parse XML strings to erlang list and then to JSON.

Example input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--some message here-->
<start>
   <data>
      <number id="333">test message</number>
      <data>current date</data>
   </data>
   <mass>
      <client>35</client>
      <address>lattitude</address>
      <code>3454343</code>
      <foo tipo="casa">Some text message 2</foo>
      <product>TEST</product>
   </mass>
</start>
```

Output should be:

```
{
  "start": {
    "data": {
      "number": {
        "@id": "333",
        "#text": "test message"
      },
      "data": "current date"
    },
    "mass": {
      "client": "35",
      "address": "lattitude",
      "code": "3454343",
      "foo": {
        "@tipo": "casa",
        "#text": "Some text message 2"
      },
      "product": "TEST"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to use erlsom:simple_form(Xml).

and getting :

```
{ok,{"start",[],
     [{"data",[],
       [{"number",[{"id","333"}],["test message"]},
        {"data",[],["current date"]}]},
      {"mass",[],
       [{"client",[],["35"]},
        {"address",[],["lattitude"]},
        {"code",[],["3454343"]},
        {"foo",[{"tipo","casa"}],["Some text message 2"]},
        {"product",[],["TEST"]}]}]},
    []}
```

Now I want to delete these empty attrs. Is there any simple way to do this?
thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Make it work w/ solution from
[Erlang, converting xml to tuples and lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517914/erlang-xml-to-tuples-and-lists?rq=1)

BUT Getting

```
{"start",
 [{"data",
   [{"number","test message"},{"data","current date"}]},
  {"mass",
   [{"client","35"},
    {"address","lattitude"},
    {"code","3454343"},
    {"foo","Some text message 2"},
    {"product","TEST"}]}]}
```

there is no `[{"id","333"}]` and `[{"tipo","casa"}]` lists.

Comment: Have you checked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517914/erlang-xml-to-tuples-and-lists?rq=1 ? This seems to be close to what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeap checked. Unfortunately that solution doesn't work for me

Comment: Then post (as an update to your question) what happens when you try the solution 3517914.

Comment: @marco.m done. thank you

Comment: Have you tried to amend that parser, or write your own, that turns that tuple list into the format you want?

Comment: @matov the main thing that I have no idea what format of xml I will get in future(theoretically). So it should be universal as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of your simple parsing is in a set format: `{Node, Attributes, Children}`, so you can write a simple parser that turns that structure you have into a nested proplist. With that, you can either use [mochijson](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/master/src/mochijson2.erl) or [jsx](https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx) to turn that proplist into a JSON string.

```
-module(transform).

-export([test/0]).

test() -> parse(data()).

parse({Node, [], [Value]}) when is_list(Value) ->
    [{Node, Value}];
parse({Node, [], Children}) ->
    V = children_to_struct(Children, []),
    [{Node, V}];
parse({Node, Attributes, Children}) ->
    V = attributes_to_struct(Attributes, []) ++ children_to_struct(Children, []),
    [{Node, V}].

children_to_struct([], Acc) -> Acc;
children_to_struct([Value], Acc) when is_list(Value) ->
    Acc ++ [{"#text", Value}];
children_to_struct([Value | T], Acc) when is_tuple(Value) ->
    children_to_struct(T, Acc ++ parse(Value)).

attributes_to_struct([], Acc) -> Acc;
attributes_to_struct([{K, V}|T], Acc) ->
    attributes_to_struct(T, Acc ++ [{"@" ++ K, V}]).

data() ->
    {"start",[],
     [{"data",[],
       [{"number",[{"id","333"}],["test message"]},
        {"data",[],["current date"]}]},
      {"mass",[],
       [{"client",[],["35"]},
        {"address",[],["lattitude"]},
        {"code",[],["3454343"]},
        {"foo",[{"tipo","casa"}],["Some text message 2"]},
        {"product",[],["TEST"]}]}]}.
```

Running it in the shell with mochijson:

```
Eshell V7.3  (abort with ^G)
1> c(transform).
{ok,transform}
2> T = transform:test().
[{"start",
  [{"data",
    [{"number",[{"@id","333"},{"#text","test message"}]},
     {"data","current date"}]},
   {"mass",
    [{"client","35"},
     {"address","lattitude"},
     {"code","3454343"},
     {"foo",[{"@tipo","casa"},{"#text","Some text message 2"}]},
     {"product","TEST"}]}]}]
3> 
4> iolist_to_binary(mochijson2:encode(T)).
<<"{\"start\":{\"data\":{\"number\":{\"@id\":[51,51,51],\"#text\":[116,101,115,116,32,109,101,115,115,97,103,101]},\"data\":{\"#text"...>>
```

Comment: thanks a LOT. works perfectly. will check your code carefully as I am learning erlang.

Answer (score 2):

i suggest to use [**jiffy**](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy) for **JSON** and [**exml**](https://github.com/paulgray/exml) for **XML**.
**jiffy** and **exml** have native code which means they are so fast.

Clone and compile them.
before compiling them, you should install **g++** and **libexpat-dev**

Example:

```
-module(test).
-export([convert/1]).
-include("exml/include/exml.hrl"). %% In my test





convert(XML) when erlang:is_binary(XML) ->
    {ok, XMLEl} = exml:parse(XML),
    jiffy:encode({[convert2(XMLEl)]}).





convert2(#xmlel{name = Name
              ,attrs = []
              ,children = [{xmlcdata, Data}]}) ->
    {Name, Data};
convert2(#xmlel{name = Name
              ,attrs = Attrs
              ,children = Children}) ->
    {Name,  {convert_attrs(Attrs) ++ convert_children(Children)}}.





convert_attrs(Attrs) ->
    convert_attrs(Attrs,[]).

convert_attrs([Attr|Attrs1], Attrs2) ->
    convert_attrs(Attrs1, [convert_attr(Attr)|Attrs2]);
convert_attrs([], Attrs2) ->
    lists:reverse(Attrs2).





convert_attr({Attr, Value}) ->
    {<<$@, Attr/binary>>, Value}.





convert_children(Children) ->
    convert_children(Children, []).

convert_children([Child|Children1], Children2) ->
    convert_children(Children1, [convert_child(Child)|Children2]);
convert_children([], Children2) ->
    lists:reverse(Children2).





convert_child({xmlcdata, Data}) ->
    {<<"#text">>, Data};
convert_child(#xmlel{}=XMLEl) ->
    convert2(XMLEl).
```

In the shell:

```
p@jahanbakhsh ~/Projects/test $ ls
exml                      jiffy                   test.erl

p@jahanbakhsh ~/Projects/test $ erl -pa jiffy/ebin exml/ebin
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2.2] [source-1ca84a4] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.2.2  (abort with ^G)
1> c(test).
{ok,test}
2> XML = <<"<start><data><number id=\"333\">test message</number><data>current date</data></data><mass><client>35</client><address>lattitude</address><code>3454343</code><foo tipo=\"casa\">Some text message 2</foo><product>TEST</product></mass></start>">>.
<<"<start><data><number id=\"333\">test message</number><data>current date</data></data><mass><client>35</client><address"...>>

3> test:convert(XML).
<<"{\"start\":{\"data\":{\"number\":{\"@id\":\"333\",\"#text\":\"test message\"},\"data\":\"current date\"},\"mass\":{\"client\":\"35\",\"addres"...>>

4> io:format("~s~n", [test:convert(XML)]).
{"start":{"data":{"number":{"@id":"333","#text":"test message"},"data":"current date"},"mass":{"client":"35","address":"lattitude","code":"3454343","foo":{"@tipo":"casa","#text":"Some text message 2"},"product":"TEST"}}}
ok
5>
```